# BaseX REST API: Set custom HTTP response header

Tags: rest, http, cors, jetty, basex

I want to include the following HTTP header to all responses by the [BaseX REST API](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/REST):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BaseX uses Jetty below the hood. You can modify the `web.xml` file to make Jetty send CORS headers, but either

- use at least BaseX 8.6.3 which added the `jetty-servlets` library or
- have to add the [`jetty-servlets`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/) jar to your `$CLASSPATH` (BaseX already ships `jetty-servlet`, which is a different class; and be sure to fetch the appropriate version matching what's included in BaseX).

Include following directives to the `web.xml` file:

```xml
<web-app>
    <!-- add those before the closing web-app tag: -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Be aware that Jetty does not seem to support posting a wildcard header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`: while the default is already

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
     <param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
```

(put that into the `<filter/>` element), Jetty uses this to construct a regular expression and always returns the value of the `Origin:` request header if matching, but that should also serve you well.

An example request:

```
$ curl -v -H "Origin: http://foo.example" http://admin:admin@localhost:8984/rest
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8984 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> GET /rest HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8984
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
> User-Agent: curl/7.50.1
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://foo.example
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 152
< Server: Jetty(8.1.18.v20150929)
< 
<rest:databases xmlns:rest="http://basex.org/rest" resources="1">
  <rest:database resources="1" size="96234589">test</rest:database>
</rest:databases>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

<strike>Given this seems a rather reasonable request and thing to do, you might be successful [opening an issue](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/issues) to include the library by default, and maybe even enabling CORS by default.</strike> (the library is now included by default)

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth answer. I've requested the feature: https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/issues/1441

Comment: I slightly adjusted the answer, so it takes into account that BaseX now ships the library.